Does casting a magic address to a pointer in C violate strict aliasing rules?
I know the following code violates strict aliasing rules
int object = 10;
int *pi = &object; // OK
float *pf = (float *)pi; // OK
float f = *pf; // undefined behavior

In the header files of microcontroller peripherals, you can often find code
#define PERIPH_BASE ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define I2C1_BASE (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x5400)
#define I2C1 ((I2C_TypeDef *) I2C1_BASE)

How legal is it according to the C language standard to access memory through a pointer I2C1?
In its simplest form, the question comes down to how much the code
*(int *)0x1234 = 10;

is it legal and does it have any claims under the strict aliasing rules?

AFAIK it is Undefined Behavior under the standard. However the respective compilers for the embedded systems out of necessity behave by design as expected in these scenarios

I don't think your object/pi/pf/f example has anything to do with the I2C1 example. The I2C1 code assumes that at address 0x40005400 there is H/W that presents its registers according to a struct I2C_TypeDef. Perfectly valid on such a system with such H/W. The C standard can't specify that certain addresses are invalid. The valid address range is system dependent.

No, the object/pi/pf/f example is related to the I2C1 example. The strict aliasing rules prevent objects of different types from having the same address. But I can "break" this rule: #define FLOAT_ACCESS *(float volatile *)0x1234 and #define INT_ACCESS *(int volatile *)0x1234 - and when using FLOAT_ACCESS = 1.1f and then INT_ACCESS = 10 I will formally violate the rules of strict aliasing.

Aliasing is claiming that there are two different objects at the same address. That is very different from claiming that there is an object somewhere., like a peripheral

Your object example violates strict aliasing rules. But, the I2C1 doesn't.

BTW, AFAICT, your object example shows "type punning" more so than a strict aliasing violation.


How legal is it according to the C language standard to access memory through a pointer I2C1?

With few exceptions (like the #error directive), the C standard does not say what is legal or not for a program. The C standard says if you write things that conform to the rules it specifies, then the standard defines the behavior.
This does not mean that if you write things that do not conform to the rules, the behavior is not defined. It only means the C standard does not define the behavior. It is still allowed for a compiler to define the behavior.

When you use a compiler that supports embedded programming, it defines the behavior. For such a compiler, there are, in effect, additional objects besides those the C standard defines with its specifications about definitions and allocating memory and whatnot. When you dereference ((I2C_TypeDef *) I2C1_BASE) with such a compiler, you are telling the compiler you are working with an I2C_Typedef object at address I2C1_BASE, and the compiler accepts that.

C 2018 4 7 says:

A conforming program is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.

This means that a program that uses features of a conforming compiler that provides extensions to the C language, and is accepted by that compiler, is a conforming program. It does obey the rules of the C standard.
Even if it “violates” the aliasing rules, that violation is rhetorical—it is a method of specifying what the C standard says or does not say in the presence of such a violation. It is not a violation in the sense that your program is not a C program or must be rejected by the compiler. Your program may still be a conforming program.
A program that does not use an extensions and does not have any output dependent on things not fully specified in the standard is a strictly conforming program. You are allowed to write programs that are conforming but not strictly conforming.

Where is the guarantee that what is defined in the standard as "undefined behavior" is redefined by the compiler implementation? The compiler documentation does not always clearly state some features. Once I encountered a situation where clang threw out a piece of my code because it contained UB. When I added some minor changes, the code was not thrown out and everything worked correctly. When I edited it again, the optimizer threw out what potentially contained UB...

...How can we rely on the compiler's reasonableness (i.e., resolution the standard's UB into a defined behavior) when this point is not specified in its description?

The standard provides definitions for several categories of behavior: undefined behavior,  unspecified behavior, implementation-defined behavior. What you are describing is more typical for implementation-defined behavior. This behavior is described as "unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made".

From the standard: "3 A program that is correct in all other aspects, operating on correct data, containing unspecified behavior shall be a correct program and act in accordance with 5.1.2.3." This is specifically about unspecified behavior. And this is logical - the program is still correct from the point of view of the standard, since there is no undefined behavior.

@EvgenyIlyin: No, this is undefined behavior. As the C standard uses the terms, “undefined behavior” means the C standard imposes no requirements, “unspecified behavior” means the C standard imposes some requirements but allows multiple possible behaviors, and “implementation-defined”  behavior means unspecified behavior for which the C standard requires the implementation to document its choices. There is no requirement that the implementation document what it does here, so this is not implemention-defined, even if an implementation chooses to document it.

The question is, if the standard says (about something) that "if...then the behavior is undefined", what should I rely on if the implementation does not legitimately describe what it will do in this case? The implementation describes implementation-define" behavior, but not all possible undefined behaviors.

The standard states that undefined behavior does not impose any requirements on behavior - it can be anything, including no behavior at all. Unlike unspecified behavior or implementation-defined behavior, we cannot know how a compiled program will behave, since even minor external conditions can cause it to behave completely differently.

And if we write a program allowing for implementation-defined behavior, we can look at the documentation and see how the compiler will act. But if the program contains code with undefined behavior, we will not see the documented behavior in the implementation. We will see something after the fact - a program that works correctly or not. The worst thing is if the program sometimes does not work, when changing lines of code in completely different places.

@EvgenyIlyin: “The question is, if the standard says (about something) that "if...then the behavior is undefined", what should I rely on if the implementation does not legitimately describe what it will do in this case?”: No, that is not the question. This answer does not address a situation in which the C standard says the behavior is undefined and the implementation does not describe what it will do.

@EvgenyIlyin: “Unlike unspecified behavior or implementation-defined behavior, we cannot know how a compiled program will behave, since even minor external conditions can cause it to behave completely differently.”: That is in invalid inference. The lack of knowledge from documentation does not imply a lack of knowledge from other sources.

As an example, I will quote from 6.3.2.3 Pointers: "7 A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined." At what specific moment does the behavior become undefined? At the moment of pointer casting or when trying to dereference it? Is the behavior undefined for run-time or in general?

For example, I intentionally write a macro with unaligned access #define UNALIGN_DATA *(volatile uint32_t *)0x123, while I know that the processor supports unaligned access and from the hardware point of view everything is legal. But from the C point of view - no, because the standard describes that the behavior is undefined, and the compiler description does not describes this UB. It turns out that I should be afraid that the behavior can be anything, since I have no sources to refute this.

@EvgenyIlyin: These comments are not relevant to this question or answer. If you wish to pursue these questions or other details, enter a new question.

Your example has nothing in common with the register access.
IMO it is well defined as I2C peripheral registers set is an object located in defined memory location. The way how the integer converts into pointer is not defined per C standards but is well defined in this implementation.

Does casting a magic address to a pointer in C violate strict aliasing
rules?

No - as tat memory contains object of type I2C_TypeDef which referenced by the pointer to this type.

The question of whether or not a program that converts integer literals to pointers is "conforming" or "standards-compliant" is meaningless.  As a result, The existence of a conforming C implementation, anywhere in the universe, which accepts a source text is sufficient to make the text conforming, while the fact that a program converts integer literals to pointers would imply that it cannot be strictly conforming.  The authors of the Standard have stated in [https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf] that they didn't intend to imply that all programs should be strictly conforming, and viewed the question of whether implementations should support a number of constructs as a "quality of implementation" matter, outside their jurisdiction.

A strictly conforming program is another term for a maximally portable program.  The goal is to give the programmer a fighting chance to make powerful C programs that are also highly portable, without seeming to demean perfectly useful C programs that happen not to be portable, thus the adverb strictly.

The maintainers of clang and gcc, however, have stated that they view the Standard's waiver of jurisdiction over a construct or corner case as implying a judgment that code relying upon that construct is "broken".  You can judge whether that's consistent with what the authors of the Standard actually wrote above, or whether such a statementis made in good or bad faith.  As a result, if one wants to use such compilers, it will be necessary to either include frequent memory barriers using the compiler-specific syntax:
asm volatile ("" ::: "memory")

for which I'd suggest defining a macro, or else ensure that an opaque function call boundary separates any code which affects the value of an object directly from code which might trigger some action that causes it to be modifies it via other means the compile won't know about.  In the absence of such barriers or opaque function calls, clang and gcc will seek to generate code whose execution time and code size are less than 100% of what would be required for the most efficient possible correct machine code accomplishing the same task.
